# How to find the calling export in Windbg

Tags: windows, windbg, crash-dumps

My process is crashing in

```
0:000> ln 7813e7a2
(7813e725)   msvcr80!_vswprintf_s_l+0x7d
(7813e7ac)   msvcr80!vswprintf_s
```

Hi have loads of loaded DLLs, how do I find out in the dump what module called the offending print?

Comment: Looks like your call stack is ruined so you won't find the offending caller

Comment: did you try running !analyze -v ?

Comment: `ln` is for `list nearest symbols`. That's not a call stack.